Metrics-server on a 1.25+ k8s cluster
I’m struggling with a metrics-server on a freshly installed 1.28 cluster. I’ve downloaded the recent 0.7.1 components yaml, but as far as I can see from logs (I relaunched the metrics-server with --v=debug switch enabled), metrics-server is failing at scraping kubelet API:
E0410 10:33:04.386093 1 scraper.go:149] “Failed to scrape node” err=“request failed, status: "403 Forbidden"” node=“k8s-wrk3.foo.bar”
I0410 10:33:04.386873 1 round_trippers.go:553] GET https://10.0.7.84:10250/metrics/resource 403 Forbidden in 1 milliseconds

I’m aware that since 1.24+ there’s no default service account token creation and this seems to be exactly the issue. I’ve created the token manually and added the secret to the service account from the yaml:
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: metrics-server
  name: metrics-server
  namespace: kube-system
secrets:
- name: metrics-server-secret
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
type: kubernetes.io/service-account-token
metadata:
  name: metrics-server-secret
  namespace: kube-system
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/service-account.name: metrics-server

But, unfortunately, this didn’t resolved the issue, metrics-server is still unable to scrape the kubelet API.
Can someone boost me up please, I’m clearly missing something crucial.
